# memory leaks found, after viewing in Snapshot view in chrome browser

Tags: angularjs, performance, memory-leaks

we are running application in chrome browser snapshot view to see memory leaks, so we found...snapshot size is keep on increasing for subsequent snaps, but i am unable to understand those objects info. so ho do i find which object/variable/array/services is causing memory leak issues. how do i fix it?

currently i am using following syntax for factory and returning instance:
 bulkController.$inject = ['factory1']; function bulkController(factory1) {

var style = factory1.getLevel1Cols(response); };

Comment: You can use the snapshot view to do a comparison (where you see the summary drop down near the top left can change that to compare) this will diff out anything already there with new objects/memory allocations.  Seems like the continuous heap snapshots with "Record Heap Allocations" would make it a bit easier to see if certain actions correspond to a jump in the heap size to make it a bit easier to pin down the correspondence between the objects shown in the heap snapshot and the actual code being executed.

Comment: Some decent instructions on using the profiling and heap measurement tools here too https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis?hl=en#visualize-memory-leaks-with-timeline-recordings